# Knockout: Make observable object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, knockout.js

I have what I thought it was a very simple question to solve... but apparently is not.

I have a server that returns a list of objects (Json) that loads from a database. As good database, all those objects have an `id` attribute which is unique:

```
{
    "stores": [
        {
            "id": "1f0",
            "name": "foo",
            "address": "foo is here street"
        },
        {
            "id": "2b4",
            "name": "bar",
            "address": "bar is here street"
        },
        {
            "id": "3b4",
            "name": "baz",
            "address": "baz is here street"
        }
    ]
}
```

The idea is pretty simple: I want to create an observable (I'm guessing I actually want an [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)) but instead of an array I want an object where the attributes are the `id` attribute and the value is the whole `store` object:

```
{
    "1f0": {
            "id": "1f0",
            "name": "foo",
            "address": "foo is here street"
         },
    "2b4": {
            "id": "2b4",
            "name": "bar",
            "address": "bar is here street"
         },
    "3b4": {
             "id": "3b4",
             "name": "baz",
             "address": "baz is here street"
         }
}
```

I don't need any of the fields (`id`, `name` or `address`) to be observables (so I don't think I need a [mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html), right?). I just want to know how to create that structure.

I've tried:

```
var self = this;
self.stores = ko.observableArray();
[ . . . ]
self.stores = ko.utils.arrayMap(
                                serverStores,
                                function(store){
                                    var retval = {};
                                    retval[store['_id']] = store;
                                    return retval;
                                });
```

But that makes `self.stores` to be an of three `Object`s like this:

```
[
    {
        "1f0": {
            "id": "1f0",
            "name": "foo",
            "address": "foo is here street"
         },
    },
    {
       "2b4": {
            "id": "2b4",
            "name": "bar",
            "address": "bar is here street"
       },
    },
    {
       "3b4": {
           "id": "3b4",
           "name": "baz",
           "address": "baz is here street"
       }
    }
]
```

Which is not what I want.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you use mapping all properties become observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't really want to `map` it, as that always returns a new array.  One option would be just to loop through the array and build up an object like:

```
var serversAsObject = {};
ko.utils.arrayForEach(serverStores, function(store) {
    var id = store.id;

    if (id) {
         serversAsObject[id] = store;
    }
});

self.stores = ko.observable(serversAsObject);
```